# How do I read this note and count it out loud?

Tags: notation, rhythm

I am struggling with understanding this pretty easy song ["Una Mattina"](https://musescore.com/user/12361686/scores/2821041) which has this note:

[image: Una Mattina"]

Can someone explain me how do I count this out loud?

Comment: It's not a note, it's 2 notes.

Answer (score 2):

While the placement of the notes may look odd since it is split over the grand staff, it is still only one voice and the rhythm is very basic. The picture you've shared has a dotted 8th note and a 16th which make up a whole beat in 4/4 (which this piece is in).

Counting straight 16ths in general would give you the following:

```
X: 1
M: 4/4
K: Cmaj
L: 1/16
"1"G"e"G"+"G"a"G "2"G"e"G"+"G"a"G "3"G"e"G"+"G"a"G "4"G"e"G"+"G"a"G |
```

Counting a dotted 8th followed by a 16ths would give you the following:

```
X: 1
M: 4/4
K: Cmaj
L: 1/16
"1"G3"a"G "2"G3"a"G "3"G3"a"G "4"G3"a"G |
```

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly semiquavers, (16th notes) so counting as Dom says is good. 1 e & a works well. Slowly but steadily the first few times.

That dotted quaver (8th note) is worth 3 semis, so imagine it's held for '1 e &' then play the B note on 'a'. If you like, pretend to press a couple of ghost notes at 'e &' to keep time more easily. But hold that A while you do.